# Making butter at home

Tags: butter

I decided to make home made butter. I haven’t done this since I was a kid. We shook the jar until the liquid separated. I wasn’t sure if this meant it was done or not even though I kept reading the instructions over and over. Now I have a cream that looks like soft cream cheese. Have I over shook? Can I still use this if I have,  or do I keep shaking?

Comment: J@J... we don’t talk down users for experimenting and making butter can be just a fun project. Heaven knows I made butter with each of my kids plus a few guests and it was never about the quality of the end product (or the economics), but about understanding and experiencing the process.

Comment: We had kitchen experiments as kids (France, late 70's) and butter was one of them. I decided to perform the experiment when my parents were away, with an electric mixer. My left buttock still remembers that day when all the butter and whatnot was all over the kitchen.

Comment: (well, in reality, I was not beaten (just never had the opportunity to use the expression about the buttock) and my parents did not even yell when they saw this, just heavily sighted - but my mom still reminds me about that from time to time. And about the campfire, we did with my brother on our wooden and varnished balcony. And the lift we blocked with us inside and then made so much noise to get out that all neighbors were out. And the time we decorated the school walls with toilet paper hanging from the roof. And , and, and ...)

Comment: @Stephie I did not talk down whatsoever.  I simply made the point that making butter at home is not economical nor does it produce a superior product.  It's fine if people want to experiment and I said absolutely nothing against that.  There is rampant disinformation out there, however, and there are those who would tell you that homemade butter is somehow special or better - it's not, and it's difficult to extract all of the buttermilk which makes it prone to rapid spoilage.  It was cautionary, nothing more.  No need to go for the nuclear option on my comments, thank you very much.

Comment: There's two different schools of making buttermilk - oddly the Jar thing is something my mom spoke of doing in india, and they used cultured yogurt made from fresh, non homogenised milk to make butter and what translated to "buttermilk with the butter removed". The other school of thought is to use fresh cream (whipping works) and then optionally culturing it?

Answer (score 22):

Keep at it.

You have made butter once you see distinct lumps in the liquid, indicating that the fat and liquid have separated.

What you described is pretty close to  whipped cream. And all bakers know not to over-whip their cream or they make butter unintentionally. You can’t over shake butter, at least not with the jar method

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about buttermilk etc. has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134645/discussion-on-answer-by-stephie-making-butter-at-home).